# Mouse click in the background inside a running app

Tags: vb.net, process, background, click, mouse

I’m making an VB application which runs another process (windowed game). My app acts as a macro to that game.

I have managed to write code that sends keyboard input into the process in the background without using appActivate, however I’m struggling to get mouse click working the same way.

I mean the program to click into specific location within the process in the background, that means I could be browsing internet or playing another game when that mouse click takes action.

Hope I make sense, can somebody bring me on right track?

This code I use to send Q letter into app in background:

```
Public Const WM_KEYDOWNLPARAM As System.UInt32 = &H320001
Public Const WM_KEYUPLPARAM As System.UInt32 = 3224502273

Public Const WM_KEYDOWN As System.Int32 = &H100
Public Const WM_KEYUP As System.Int32 = &H101


<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function PostMessage(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.In()> ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.In()> ByVal Msg As System.UInt32, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.In()> ByVal wParam As System.IntPtr, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.In()> ByVal lParam As System.UIntPtr) As System.Boolean
End Function

Public Sub InputPressKey(ByVal Handle As System.IntPtr, ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys)
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, CType(Key, System.IntPtr), CType(WM_KEYDOWNLPARAM, System.UIntPtr))
End Sub

Public Sub InputReleaseKey(ByVal Handle As System.IntPtr, ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys)
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_KEYUP, CType(Key, System.IntPtr), CType(WM_KEYUPLPARAM, System.UIntPtr))
End Sub


InputPressKey(Process.MainWindowHandle, System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Q)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a little code...it's going to be hard for anyone to suggest anything useful without seeing the code you're simulating input events with. Like are you using keyboard/mouse hooks or what?

Comment: Apologies, I did not think that would be helpful. Post edited.

Comment: There are constants for mouse events just like the WM_KEYDOWN/UP ones you're already using, have you tried those?

Comment: I haven’t tried because I have no idea how to construct such code, hence I’m here

Comment: `Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As System.UInt32 = &H201` and `Private Const WM_LBUTTONUP As System.UInt32 = &H202`. Then use `PostMessage(Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1,MakeLParam(x,y))` followed by `PostMessage(Handle,WM_LBUTTONUP, 1,MakeLParam(x,y))` to post the message just like you've been doing for the keys. Down then up does a click, and (x,y) are the coordinates you want to click at.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Even though soohoonigan was nice to provide a solution, Stack Overflow is not the right place to go when _needing_ code. We're here to answer and solve specific questions or problems, not to write the code for you or point you in the right direction. For future reference please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I’ll give this a go tonight thanks mate!

Comment: I want to declare these:
    Public Const WM_RBUTTONDOWNLPARAM As System.UInt32 = ?
    Public Const WM_RBUTTONUPLPARAM As System.UInt32 = ? What values should be used here?

Comment: [List of windows messages](https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages). Find what you need, and convert it to vb hex format. Google an online converter if you don't know how to format the value.